# Broadcom 43142 Bluetooth not working

Tags: linux, debian, bluetooth, lenovo-laptop, broadcom

I am using a Lenovo B590 running Debian Jessie

```
❆ ~ け (ke) ➭ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 004: ID 058f:6366 Alcor Micro Corp. Multi Flash Reader
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 2516:0004
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 1bcf:2c0c Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc.
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 04ca:2007 Lite-On Technology Corp.
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0461:4d0f Primax Electronics, Ltd HP Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

dmesg

```
❆ ~ を (o) ➭ dmesg | grep -i 'blue'
[    6.164430] thinkpad_acpi: rfkill switch tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: radio is unblocked
[   21.806305] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.17
[   21.806345] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   21.806352] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   21.806355] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   21.806359] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   23.516886] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   23.516891] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   23.516899] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[  394.437579] Bluetooth: HIDP (Human Interface Emulation) ver 1.2
[  394.437589] Bluetooth: HIDP socket layer initialized
```

But still nothing found

```
❆ ~ に (ni) ➭ hcitool dev
Devices:
❆ ~ く (ku) ➭ hcitool scan
Device is not available: No such device
```

Devices

```
❆ ~ ト (to) ➭ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family U        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: noSB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 07)
```

Rfkill list

```
❆ ~ カ (ka) ➭ rfkill list
0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Bluetooth is enabled (as seen in `/proc/acpi/ibm/bluetooth`), I have installed bluez/blueman/gnome-applet

When I try to run bt-device I get

```
❆ ~ リ (ri) ➭ bt-device -l
**
ERROR:lib/bluez/adapter.c:165:adapter_get_dbus_object_path: assertion failed (ADAPTER_IS(self))
[1]    10579 abort      bt-device -l
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Did you tried: hciconfig hci0 up ?

Comment: Look at this. I have to complete the 30 characters...oh, God
http://askubuntu.com/questions/632336/bluetooth-broadcom-43142-isnt-working-on-ubuntu-15-04

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a bug in `bluez-utils`:
https://github.com/khvzak/bluez-tools/issues/23

A workaround proposed [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1731068#p1731068) is to reload the `btusb` kernel module.

```
rmmod btusb
modprobe btusb
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you don't have right drivers for the chip to work.
I also have the same Broadcom device on my laptop and take my word, it is the worst network device out there.

The reason behind that is, first, it is a combined chip for both Bluetooth and Wireless LAN. Second, the driver. I have wasted a lot of time finding drivers for Ubuntu.

If it's any help, you can install drivers in Ubuntu by this command-

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

(First you have to update the repository by `apt-get update`.)

Ubuntu is also a Debian based OS, so the binaries should be compatible (I am not completely sure).
You can test this package in Debian. Maybe the trick will work.

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for this issue and solve it.
So here is my solution

- Hardware: Lenovo Thinkpad T460s
- OS: Linux
- Distro:

```
$ uname -a
Linux localhost 5.10.0-19-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.149-2 (2022-10-21) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

- Download firmware file: [broadcom-bt-firmware/brcm/BCM43142A0-105b-e065.hcd](https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware/blob/master/brcm/BCM43142A0-105b-e065.hcd)
- Copy the file to `/lib/firmware/brcm/`
- Reload mod
  rmmod btusb
  modprobe btusb